# Google app engine:Where is the datastore file stored on the local development server?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am working on a google app engine project using python. I want to know where does google app engine stores the datastore for the projects. I have tried but could not  find it.

Can anyone please help me? I am using windows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my Windows machine the datastore file is stored in:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\(yourusername)\Local Settings\Temp
```

It'll have a `.datastore` extension.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Got it in the temp directory.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to manage `datastore` file in your own directory, you can set the `datastore` path with command line arguments. See this [document](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments).

> --datastore_path=...
>     The path to use for the local datastore data file. The server creates this file if it does not exist.