# How to check local GAE datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been playing with Google Appengine and want to check if the application is populating data in the local datastore. Where is this file located?

Comment: Which OS are you using, and why do you doubt that the database is being populated?

Comment: The answer for Windows is here by the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264267/google-app-enginewhere-is-the-datastore-file-stored-on-the-local-development-ser

Comment: On MacOS the datastore is put into a tmp directory by default. This means it gets deleted every time you reboot, which can lead to confusion/frustration. You should get in the habit of starting up the dev_appserver with the --datastore_path parameter so you know where it's saving data.

Comment: The solution here was fine on windows

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rather than looking at the datastore file, you should probably just be visiting `http://localhost:8002/datastore` where there's a datastore browser available. Replace `8002` with whatever the admin port is for your GAE project.

Comment: Worked well on Windows

Answer (score 10):

In the latest version, the datastore browser is found at

```
http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly specify the datastore path with a command line argument: `--datastore_path`

Comment: @Brig: it's system-dependent; the datastore stub uses `tempfile`.  It's in /tmp on unix-like systems.

Comment: it certainly uses the `tempfile` module, but on Mac, the directory is `/var/folders/mg/[some_random_string]/T`. I am guessing it's different per device. Just open the python interpreter and `import tempfile` then `print tempfile.gettempdir()`