# Where does App Engine dev_appserver store the datastore?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, dev-appserver

Google App Engine dev_appserver.py has an argument `--datastore_path` to specify where the datastore is saved.

If you don't specify this, where is it saved by default? I would like to make a backup. I am running windows 8, but a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753914/does-anyone-know-where-the-google-app-engine-local-datastore-file-located-for-ma) for OSX was closed.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been asked before (I couldnt find it earlier).
[Google app engine:Where is the datastore file stored on the local development server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264267/google-app-enginewhere-is-the-datastore-file-stored-on-the-local-development-se?rq=1)

It file is in 
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\appengine.appbfw

Comment: Instead of duplicating the answer, close your question as duplicate of that one